# Collapsing parts of PHP code in an IDE (Eclipse)

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

I am trying to find the best PHP IDE for me on the Mac, I like Eclipse and Netbeans but I for some reason I can't collapse PHP code, it only collapses the HTML parts, I'm guessing that  I am missing an option somewhere? Both Coda and TextMate can collapse php code ok but I *need* code completion and realtime syntax checking.

Any advice would be very nice.

Thank You.

Comment: Real programmers don't need syntax checking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to 'Window' > 'Preferences' and expand the 'PHP' group. Expand 'Editor' and then click 'Code Folding'. There should be a check box at the top that will let you enable/disable code folding. Inside of your PHP editor you should now see a little icon to the left of the code for folding the block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed some PHP editor plugin? Try [PHPEclipse](http://www.phpeclipse.com/)
it should solve the collapsing issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're really into eclipse for PHP editing, you should have a look at [PHP Developement Tools for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/). It provides syntax highlighting (and checking), code completion and (most importantly for you) folding.

It's unclear from your question if you have it installed. if you do, follow @Aaron's response.